# (1) Determine the amount of statues

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, parsing

Inspired by this stack of little statues that are currently on my desk at work, given to me by my colleagues from Sri Lanka when they visited The Netherlands:

[image]

This is split into two different challenges due to popular demand:
Part 1) Determine the amount of statues (this challenge)
Part 2) [Can the statues be stacked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/216361/52210)

### Challenge 1:

**Input:**

\$statues\$: a multi-line string (or character matrix), containing only the characters  `\n|-#` (where the  `|-#` can be other characters of your own choice)

**Output:**

The amount of statues in the input.

**Statues input example:**

```
      ##|
####    |
# ##
#  #  |##
----  |######
      |   ###
|##   |##   #
|## - |######
    # |####
```

The `|` and `-` represent the bases of the statues. So with the input above, we'll have the following statues:

```
       ####
       ## #
       ## ##
####   #  ##
# ##  ## ###  ##      #
#  #  ## ###  ##  #   #
----  ------  --  -  --
```

So the output will be `5`.

### Challenge rules:

- You can use a different consistent character other than `#`, `-`, and/or `|` for the statue if you want ( `\n` are mandatory, though). Please state which one you've used in your answer if it's different than the defaults.
- You are allowed to take the \$statues\$ input in any reasonable format. Can be a multi-line string, a list/array/stream of strings, a character matrix, etc.
- You are allowed to pad the statues input with trailing spaces so it's a rectangle.
- You can assume statues are always separated by at least one space or blank line from one-another, so something like `#|#|` or `#||#` won't be in the input.
- You can assume the statues will only have a base at ones side, so a statue like this won't be in the input:

```
##|
##|
--
```

- It is possible that a smaller statue is within the rectangular boundaries of another oddly shaped statue. For example, this is possible:

```
# ##
- ##
  ##
####
# # 
----
```

- Statues will never be inside of each other, though. So something like this won't be in the input:

```
 #####
##   #
#  # #
# ## ##
# -- ##
#     #
##    #
-------
```

- You can assume the base determines the width of a statue. So you won't have statues like these in the input:

```
#######
 #####
 ####     ###
  ---     --
```

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test cases:

```
      ##|
####    |
# ##
#  #  |##
----  |######
      |   ###
|##   |##   #
|## - |######
    # |####

Output: 5
__________________________________________________

# ##
- ##
  ##
####
# # 
----

Output: 2
__________________________________________________

      #
|###  #
| #   #
|#### -

Output: 2
__________________________________________________

--- ##|
### ##|
###
### |#

Output: 3
__________________________________________________

####             #####|
# ##
###              |#           |#
#####            |#           |##
-----            |#           |#
                 |#
                 |#
                 |#

Output: 4
__________________________________________________

|# |# |# |# |# #| #| #|

Output: 8
__________________________________________________

|##
|   ##
|#  --

Output: 2
__________________________________________________

      |##
----  |####
# ##
###   |#
      |#  ###|
      |#    #|
      |#   ##|
      |#

Output: 4
__________________________________________________

- |##
#      #
  #| ###
  #| ---

Output: 4
__________________________________________________

#
####
----

--
 #

Output: 2
__________________________________________________
##
##
--

--
##
##

Output: 2
```

Comment: The second-to-last test case has an `_` instead of `-`. This does look better, but it is not intended, right?

Comment: @ovs Woops.. should be fixed.

Comment: [suggested test case](https://dzaima.github.io/paste#0U1bmUlbm0tUFIWUQGwA)

Comment: @Razetime The statues are guaranteed to be split by at least a space or blank line. But if you want I can add [this test case](https://dzaima.github.io/paste#0U1bmUlbm0tXlAmFlEAcA)? (I've edited newline to blank line in the rules.)

Comment: Yeah, that's also similar.

Comment: @Razetime Added

Comment: Not voting to close, but is this a disguised duplicate of [find the islands](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188874/to-find-islands-of-1-and-0-in-matrix/)?  The only difference is here you have to first do a pass to convert the `|-` characters into 1 and everything else to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
,ZŒrFċ¥"Ø^S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/18n6uikIrcj3YeWKh2eERf8/@HuLYfb//9XAANl5RgQxaUMBCAGlKcA4SlAeQpAFAMR4tIHAjAPBLggSmLAJilzQdRASAhPH0WlMoSnoAAA)

The statues have a polished bottom, so they use `/` instead of `-` and `\` instead of `|`. The input is a list of strings that must be the same length.

### Explanation

```
,ZŒrFċ¥"Ø^S   Main monadic link
,             Pair the input
 Z            with the input transposed
  Œr          Run-length encode everything
       "      Zip with
      ¥       (
    F           Flatten left argument
     ċ          Count the occurences of right argument
      ¥       )
        Ø^    with "/\"
          S   Sum
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
„-|v€Åγ˜y¢Iø}Š+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcM83ZqyR01rDree23x6TuWhRZ6Hd9QeXaD939Pr0G4dLiUuBV07BSV7HYX/0dFKCko6CrgJZThRg1VJrI5CNJIiBIHNMEJGKBA2QoEYIxSwGFFDwGywEbogNhqB0wgMAmwEfqfW4A1iqBH4nYpfFo8RupR7RJmwEbDgjAUA)

**Commented:**

```python
„-|              # push string literal "-|"
   v        }    # iterate over this string
    €Åγ          #   run-length encode each line of the input / transposed input
                 #   this pushes the chunk elements and the chunk lengths
       ˜         #   flatten the list
        y¢       #   count the chunks of the current character
          Iø     #   push the transposed input to the stack for the second iteration
             Š   # triple-swap: move the transposed input to bottom
              +  # sum both counts
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>93</s> <s>86</s> <s>61</s> 58 bytes

*Saved seven bytes, thanks to [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)!*
*Saved three bytes, thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!*

```ruby
->s{((s.transpose*"").scan(/\|+/)+(s*"").scan(/-+/)).size}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVLbasMwDH3XV4gYRrLi9r3Q/kibhyxL2kBu2Alsa/rtmSW7npNCnyaMbV2scyRLjR/fc3mY5VHf4lhvB5W1uu908R5FyVbnWRvvztNml2xiHZiksZh79VPcZ4HXou4LheXY5kPVtTh02Kvuc8wLbLJBVV/YlZhfM6WxVF2DzVgPVV21BWrjbS@4T@CCB5TH5laemq3u62qIo3Nr8Jqsj9/2/DhJ7wA9Xk4Rsggx0QHCCF2chlZDp6FZkzWBNMIaCdiQiTMJsDF2t5pcRAqrIUapY0FIIJH9ZuNIY7MwPspxpYyCT/QIhOHjiJqpiNL401VnkANUEdRn2yBcJ3zNq4i1wDoFASwULka8iBBcpHyZ4wl3WqH@R4Tvy8Rt8st0hFfgp5dgvxsozdMnuTFZzMlzQ133HkTgjxf9A4Q0l@raG5CXDhvEY1yQ6Qt3CQdKPGaeaYIjTEQWw0kDCeynndUonX8B)

Takes input as a matrix of characters.

Comment: [-3(takes list of lines)](https://tio.run/##rVLBbsIwDL37K6J4mlpQyn0S/Ahw6BCwTmupGnYYhG/vYjvN0lbiNCtq4vjV79lx9/3@05/WvdnYe2aLumyz17fDR9nZvLh2ZWPbiz2G689L1eSLl1Ve2EPZZKudW9K5uh2XtqBgpvUQM0Po0Z/XZlPfT9u6sO1Xdc30rtH5/gGtOm@1YkN0tAF6o0PwlHgqeMovJ1dgvLFHBgJxnAlBMPIVz4yQKJ5Seg@igpjAKI77DyP9ndBEVNBKGZF3FRmII@JImq@I0sQ9VOeZE1ZM6pM2YOhErHmCmBpMUxDByOFi8AkCuUjzNMeM101Y/wMR@@K4TXH5jvBK4vQnyHMDpZk9UhiT0ZzMGxq6NwiBP130DpDKHLvTaCLeBG7AYVwUy8dwSAcKh5lnmRAEkxAZzv4X "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks, I further saved 3 bytes by `s*""` ;-)

Comment: [-1 using `*""` again](https://tio.run/##rVJNb4MwDL3nV1hYmqBV6L1S@0faHhiDNhMkKIFDV/rbWb7IApV6mhWR2Hn4PTuWw@d9qg8TPapHqvK26NKPfXkrpMryXhZcdUJVPvwtGM82SZLlqix4ujuP250@s59qm6ooTufwc7oe6LF91Kc2V13D@jQ58yS7PAHhVjVdJaEeeNkzwaEX0EnxNZQVFFIWdxA1qF4yflVQS9FCOzQ9axivfBj2GSEdXE8JWEMczUZQmzl4D5wH3tPMMLoQodqsZ4w4yGgzIXEY93UeXSDReQDJxaswTISCvdcfi9QxRxNQXqvJiHaHwGA4As5I0xWZNGH31WnmiBWj@lwb0Hci1LxCrI2sUxiChWOLwTcItEXStzleeMcV638gQl9G26awdEfsiu7Nn8Q9NzFpXh7Jj8liTl4b6rs3CyF/usw7kFjm0l3fRuKp5yY4jwtY@egP8UDhPPNWJvGCjRA3nNMv "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: You can replace `(&:join)` with a block `{_1*""}` if you're fine with using 2.7

Comment: @Razetime - Ah, yes! I'll edit that too in a moment.

Comment: If you concatenate both scan results and take the length of that, this is 3 bytes shorter: `->s{((s.transpose*"").scan(/\|+/)+(s*"").scan(/-+/)).size}`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 37 bytes

```
-+|(?<=(.)*)¦(?!.*¶(?<-1>.)*(?(1)$)¦)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fV7tGw97GVkNPU0vz0DINe0U9rUPbgCK6hnZAIQ17DUNNFaCE5v//CmCgrHxoGZcyEIA4ICZQBEgoKIN4QKYuEECYIMAF0XRoGVinMhdIXAEiDRKB8HVRlStDuQA) Uses `¦` instead of `|`. Explanation:

```
-+|
```

Count runs of `-`s, or...

```
(?<=(.)*)¦(?!.*¶(?<-1>.)*(?(1)$)¦)
```

... any `¦`s which do not have a `¦` directly underneath them on the next line. This uses a .NET balancing group to ensure that the two `¦`s are vertically aligned.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `(-p)`, <s>50</s>, 30 bytes

Using `I` instead of `|` (first rule), and padding input with trailing spaces so it's a rectangle (third rule).

```perl
/
/;$_=()=/-+|I(?!.{@{-}}I)/gs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVRhS8NADP2eXxHJoBtyq8wVZFIUQeS@6E/oJxFhuLJ1INT@desll7W9DgbeFo5eXxte0veaK9@366x9en6xr/UkzZMi@c5ucJ4AJE2bQno/KfLpLE/N9Y@dPlzN68faNI2dpR@7tkUJIssbkAu@UYQeoSJ0y/pHYFwI4gCfYoWJwOf4q0cmyCSPHAu87atyX60wg@LfAdIgGBRad5EC7pnvridfRJGrMtw/yY7d9/AXnUvP@jnZueluVwucPANpbuOkoYF33mJSlzs/RxnjgDEF9xUAqUInMkicMCc5juraUdWLZHRyLqPktGJKt5yQsnrau0ha7hP84HARvNR/q3MaDOqx62rxQS3oxeOfBYZahnD89nyFjbYMdBg8FI1Jb4KJXkYeF3rE6fnAwgAG59AicthASJlSwYDxd1NWn5uvXWvW5R8)

How

- `/-+|I(?=.{@{-}}I)/gs` to match `-` runs or `|` not followed by `|` bellow
- `(()=...)` list context
- `$_=` list is coerced to int size

Saved 13 bytes negating the lookahead, similarly to @Neil's retina answer.

Comment: Nice use of the Saturn operator `=()=`!

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 36 bytes

```
ＷＳ«Ｆι«Ｆ²⊞υ›⁼κ§-|λ⁼⊟ＫＤ²✳∨⊗λ⁴κκ»⸿»⎚ＩΣυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BawMhEIXP9VcM62UE9xJ666kkpeSUhVx7sRvblbVr6mpaqPntdtRA6UMe3xvnoeOk/OiUzflrMlYD7pdzDMfgzfKOQsAPu3tzHtBUbLwRMMR1wijh2WsVtMenz6jsirOEx7BfTvobuz51EqwQEm6XgzvjoPW8M16PwbgFNxL@wsHjzsVXq09oqXQvROnO5A/08EAfCjgXvrJb6l58R4Mr21qtPBK2@VatAY/xA2Mp5wxVnCfGSYWJKJMBnUTUkyoVsVZItcRZqp3mLfX/NnlLLPcX@ws) Link is to verbose version of code. Finally managed to beat Retina. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ«
```

Repeat on each line of input.

```
Ｆι«
```

Repeat on each character.

```
Ｆ²⊞υ›⁼κ§-|λ⁼⊟ＫＤ²✳∨⊗λ⁴κ
```

If the character is a `-` or a `|`, then check whether the character to the left is also a `-` or character above is also a `|` as appropriate. Record whether this character therefore begins a new statue.

```
κ»⸿»
```

Print the character and start a new line for every line of the input.

```
⎚ＩΣυ
```

Print the total number of statues seen.

My previous 38-byte approach used direct calculation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υιＩΣ⁺Ｅυ⁻№ι-Ｌ⌕Ａι--ＥＥθ⭆υ§λκ⁻№ι|Ｌ⌕Ａι||
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1NCoMwEIX3OcVgNiPEE3QlQkGoIPQE0oqGptFq0naRu6cTx00LfeTvm3nzchm75TJ1JsbXqE0PWNvZu7NbtB0wz6H164hegc4PoqWiw6pbHZ79HVvjV2y6ObUbbQmqyZNBK8iKLFdw6u3gRjxqey2N4To1SDRAc2k/FPBne1Dpanvt32gU3Nj4kxz@JIewJScdYoRNUoZ0CUlKj52ACXYCWoFLoiBtlCTYErYkKdjDJ1Px5ZRMlBKLp/kA) Link is to verbose version of code. Requires padded input. Explanation: Each base of each horizontal statue contains a number `n` `-`s. But it also contains `n-1` `--`s, if you include overlaps, which the `FindAll` command does. Therefore the number of horizontal statues in a line is the number of `-`s minus the number of overlapping `--`s. It then remains to transpose the input and count the difference between the number of `|`s and the number of overlapping `||`s.